# VHDL - Do I have to use the same clock signal in every sequential processes?

Tags: vhdl, clock, fpga, timing, sequential

I have a big problem synthesizing a VHDL code. I am quit new to FPGA designs.

I have multiple sequential processes, and the clock of certain processes is a result of others, like in the code below :

```
process( clk_100MHz )
    begin
       if( clk_100MHz'event and clk_100MHz = '1') then
           clk_divider_4 <= clk_divider_4 + 1;
           clk_25MHz <= clk_divider(1);
        end if;
end process;

process( clk_25MHz )
    begin
       if( clk_25MHz'event and clk_25MHz = '1') then

        -- Some sequantial code here

       end if;
end process;
```

Is that a problem ? Because I have the feeling that the problem of my code is due to a timing issue and that this could be the cause.

Thank you for your answers,

Damien.

Comment: To the downvoter: Please provide a short comment for the reason to downvote, since that will help newcomers to improve their questions.

Comment: Are you transferring data between both clock domains? Are there a lof of registers connected to `clk_25MHz`?

Comment: Use one single clock throughout unless you have a REALLY good reason to do otherwise. Then, use "clock domain crossing" techniques to resolve problems - see also "input synchronisers" for asynchronous inputs. Within that clock domain, use clock enables (Morten's answer) for related clocks.

Answer (score 2):

Clocks in an FPGA are typically input from external pins or generated by PLLs, since that greatly helps timing closure based on Static Timing Analysis (STA).  So don't derive clocks based on logic, unless you really know that what you are doing.

So the way to update some logic at e.g. 25 MHz rate using a 100 MHz clock, is to have an enable signal that is only asserted at 1:4, with code like:

```
process (clk_100MHz) is
  variable enable_25MHz_div : natural range 0 to 3 := 0;
begin
  if rising_edge(clk_100MHz) then
    if enable_25MHz_div = 0 then
      ...  -- Code up update at 25 MHz rate
    end if;
    -- Enable at 25 MHz rate based on clock division
    if enable_25MHz_div = 3 then
      enable_25MHz_div := 0;
    else
      enable_25MHz_div := enable_25MHz_div + 1;
    end if;
  end if;
end process;
```

Using the same 100 MHz clock for all the logic in the design enabled direct exchange of data between the different processes, since all data is referenced to the same clock, even if actual update of values may occur at different rate.